# setup.bash must source again when restart

Tags: ros, source, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

why I have to source setup.bash again when restart my computer?

```
adminyin@adminyin-System:~$ cd catkin_ws/src/
adminyin@adminyin-System:~/catkin_ws/src$ ls
beginner_tutorials  CMakeLists.txt
adminyin@adminyin-System:~/catkin_ws/src$ rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials
[rospack] Error: no such package beginner_tutorials
adminyin@adminyin-System:~/catkin_ws/src$ cd ..
adminyin@adminyin-System:~/catkin_ws$ source devel/setup.bash 
adminyin@adminyin-System:~/catkin_ws$ cd src/
adminyin@adminyin-System:~/catkin_ws/src$ rospack depends1 beginner_tutorials
roscpp
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224894/setup.bash-must-source-again-when-restart/) by [yin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25699/yin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2016-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because it only changes environment variables in your *current bash session*. Please see [wiki/Ubuntu install of ROS Jade - Environment setup](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Ubuntu#jade.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-DebEnvironment.Environment_setup).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yin](https://answers.ros.org/users/25699/yin/) on 2016-02-21**:
OK，thank you.